# Exact regex match with ampersand words

Tags: php, regex

How can I not match "software" on its own but only "software & framework"?

```
$skill = array("software & framework","communication skills","technology-based","software","technology");

$text = "software & framework and technology-based and excel technology- communication";

foreach ($skill as $skills) {

preg_match_all("~(?<![\w-])" . preg_quote($skills) . "(?![\w-])~i", $text, $matchWords);

foreach ($matchWords[0] as $matchWord) {

echo "<b>MatchWord:</b> " . $matchWord.  "<br>";

}
```

**Current results:**

- MatchWord: software & framework
- MatchWord: technology-based
- MatchWord: software

**Expected results:**

- MatchWord: software & framework
- MatchWord: technology-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a single pattern with alternations dynamically:

```
$pattern = '~(?<![\w-])(?:' . implode('|', array_map(function($i) {
     return preg_quote($i, '~');
}, $skill)) . ')(?![\w-])~i';
```

Then, you may extract the matches:

```
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matchWords)) {
  print_r($matchWords[0]);
}
```

Output: `Array ([0] => software & framework [1] => technology-based )`

**NOTE**: if the iterms in the `$skill` array are not sorted by length in the descending order, you need to do that beforehand using, for example:

```
usort($skill, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});
```

See the [full PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ItXMg).