# Using preg_replace to get characters before/after match

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code to get characters before/after the regex match:

```
$searchterm = 'blue';
$string = 'Here is a sentence talking about blue.  This sentence talks about red.';
$regex = '/.*(.{10}\b' . $searchterm . '\b.{10}).*/si';
echo preg_replace($regex, '$1', $string);
```

**Output:** "ing about blue.  This se" (expected).

When I change $searchterm = 'red', then I get this:

**Output:** "Here is a sentence talking about blue.  This sentence talks about red."

I am expecting this: "lks about red."  The same thing happens if you start at the beginning of the sentence.  Is there a way to use a similar regex to not pull back the entire string when it's at the start/end?

Example of what is happening: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e500b505860ded429e78869f61dbf4128ff368b3

Comment: Not a correct dupe as OP already knows how to match 10 characters.

Comment: Well, even if it is not the exact dupe, it is exactly the missing bit. Also, since the answer not following best practices is accepted, this post should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for accepting that dupe wasn't correct. And it is prerogative of OP to chose whatever answer works for him/her. We have thousands of answers on SO that have better answers than the accepted one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You regex regex is almost correct but make sure to use a non-greedy quantifier with `.{0,10}` limit for surrounding substring:

```sh
$searchterm = 'blue';
$string = 'Here is a sentence talking about blue.  This sentence talks about red.';
$regex = '/.*?(.{0,10}\b' . $searchterm . '\b.{0,10}).*/si';
echo preg_replace($regex, '$1', $string);
```

[Updated Code Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21e7668391f09c368f903e1112f28c659a2ee03c)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h5py9y/1)

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use `preg_match` with `.{0,10}` quantifiers instead of `{10}`,

```php
function truncateString($searchterm){
    $string = 'Here is a sentence talking about blue.  This sentence talks about red.';
    $regex = '/.{0,10}\b' . $searchterm . '\b.{0,10}/si';
    if (preg_match($regex, $string, $m)) {
        echo $m[0] . "\n";
    }  
}

truncateString('blue');
// => ing about blue.  This se
truncateString('red');
// => lks about red.
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/mJnSG).

`preg_match` will find and return the first match only. The `.{0,10}` pattern will match *zero to ten* occurrences of any char (since the `s` modifier is used, the `.` matches even line break chars).

One more thing: if your `$searchterm` can contain special regex metacharacters, anywhere in the term, you should consider refactoring the code to

```php
$regex = '/.{0,10}(?<!\w)' . preg_quote($searchterm, '/') . '(?!\w).{0,10}/si';
```

where `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` are *unambiguous word boundaries* and the `preg_quote` is used to escape all special chars.

Comment: Please do not extend your question via comment.  Take a moment to understand these answer, then try to adjust them yourself.  After some time, toil, and research, then ask a new question if you are stuck.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out and figured it would be better if it were self contained in this question than posting a new one.

Comment: Stack Overflow pages are not forum threads that read chronologically like a top-to-bottom conversation.  There must be only one question on a page (and that question should be 100% in the question body at the top of the page.  There is nothing wrong with asking two questions that are related -- they just need to be different.  Please do not get stuck in a cycle of help vampirism.  If you are a developer, please act like one and put in real effort between questions.

Comment: @user2096091 I think you are asking about using `preg_quote` within an `array_map`, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032816/exact-regex-match-with-ampersand-words/59033014#59033014). You would just need to change `~` to `/` as you are using `/` as a regex delimiter. I'd really urge you to use the right method for the current task, and it is `preg_match`. With `.*` or `.*?` at the start, you end up with a lot of redundant backtracking that you do not get with `preg_match` pattern (note the `.*` at the end of a regex pattern has no impact on matching performance).